# How i can do multiple webview with bottom tab bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, webview, bottomtabs

I'm new in Flutter and mobile app programming. I am started with a webview application. But i have a problem. I seen multiple webview does not working Android app. Only first webview loaded. When change tab webview not changed. I need to each tab need different url.I am using bottomtab bar.

any suggestions? Thanks!

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'My Application';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  
  
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    WebView(
      // 1. web view
      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

    ),
    WebView(
       // 2. web view
      initialUrl: 'https://www.apple.com/',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      // 3. web view
    ),
    WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://www.microsoft.com/',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

    ),
  ];



  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset('assets/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,  height: 32,),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(121, 186, 56,1)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(121, 186, 56,1),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem >[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Tips',
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            label: 'Online Form',
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: u find any solution..iam also facing the same problem!